# Autoloading ruby gem warning, may be causing Heroku application error?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, tilt

I have a very simple Ruby [Serve](http://get-serve.com/) prototype website, which works fine locally but doesn't work on Heroku:

```
Aug 02 12:35:40 localp app/web.1:  [2013-08-02 11:35:40] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1 
Aug 02 12:35:40 localp app/web.1:  [2013-08-02 11:35:40] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux] 
Aug 02 12:35:40 localp app/web.1:  [2013-08-02 11:35:40] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=4000 
Aug 02 12:36:39 localp heroku/web.1:  Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch 
Aug 02 12:36:39 localp heroku/web.1:  Stopping process with SIGKILL 
Aug 02 12:36:41 localp heroku/web.1:  Process exited with status 137 
Aug 02 12:36:41 localp heroku/web.1:  State changed from starting to crashed
```

I *think* it may have something to do with gems not loading properly, as this is the **local** warning I get:

```
[2013-08-02 12:39:22] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-08-02 12:39:22] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-10-12) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
[2013-08-02 12:39:22] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=79265 port=4000
WARN: serve autoloading 'slim' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'slim' suggested.
WARN: serve autoloading 'slim' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'slim' suggested.
WARN: serve autoloading 'slim' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'slim' suggested.
WARN: serve autoloading 'slim' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'slim' suggested.
WARN: tilt autoloading 'redcarpet' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'redcarpet' suggested.
WARN: tilt autoloading 'rdiscount' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'rdiscount' suggested.
127.0.0.1 - local [02/Aug/2013 12:40:10] "GET /wireframes/ HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.2049
127.0.0.1 - local [02/Aug/2013 12:40:10] "GET /styles/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 765 0.0018
127.0.0.1 - local [02/Aug/2013 12:40:10] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 31 0.0026
```

I have tried requiring gems explicitly but I get the same error message. Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'serve', '1.5.2'

gem 'rack-contrib'
gem 'compass'
gem 'sass-globbing'
gem 'rdiscount', :require => 'rdiscount'
gem 'slim', :require => 'slim'
```

FWIW, here is my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
```

I've had a look all over Stack Overflow. There are some answers but they relate to precompiling assets on Rails. Any ideas what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WEBrick is a Ruby webserver designed for development and not recommended for production use. It's also *multithreaded*.

Try adding `gem "thin"` to your Gemfile. Heroku will then use Thin as the server, which is not multithreaded (by default though it has a threaded option), and your `non thread-safe way` will probably go away.

Comment: Ahh, didn't realise heroku was a production environment per se.

I added `gem 'thin'` and I'm not getting a `non-thread safe way` loading warning. 

However, I'm still getting an [Application Error](https://gist.github.com/growdigital/6155329) from Heroku: `Error R10 (Boot timeout)`. Thanks for suggestion, will investigate further on [Serve users forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/serve-users)

Comment: This does fix the warning messages. Alas for me, the application error on heroku is caused by something else! :(